# Largest orthogonal matrix that can be created using only 1 and -1 as elements

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to understand what is the largest possible orthogonal matrix that can be created using only 1 and -1 as its elements.

Clearly for a $\ 4 \times 4 $ matrix:

We can construct an orthogonal matrix as :
$\  \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&1\\1&-1&-1&-1\\1&-1&1&1\end{bmatrix} $

But I want to understand whether it is possible to prove that we can or cannot create such a matrix for larger size of the matrix.

Any guidance is appreciated :)

My attempts until now have been restricted to finding bounds on column rank of a matrix with all  possible column vectors constructed from 1 and -1.

But even then, I am unable to link it to orthogonality of vectors.

Comment: I guess you mean that matrix divided by $\sqrt{4}$. The rows (and columns) of an orthogonal matrix are unit vectors.

Comment: @lcv: Not necessarily, I want that the columns should be orthogonal even if they are not orthonormal (unit length). I keep this for convenience sake btw.

Comment: "largest possible orthogonal matrix", do you mean $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $n$ is maximal?

Comment: @BMath: Yes, sort of.

Comment: there are $2^{(n^2)}$ $n$x$n$ matrices made with ones and negative ones. For small $n$ you can compute if there exists (one or possibly more) orthogonal matrices

Comment: If $n$ is odd, than it is impossible because the inproduct of to columns will always be $\pm1 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Gabrielek : Thanks for the reply, but without such computations, I am curious for a more linear algebra style argument for such a proof of existence.

Comment: Before you start to go ahead in a quite unsual problem, a good proof check with brutal force can help to understand if the answer could be "yes" or "no". Otherwise you risk to conjecture the existence of infinite Fermat's prime numbers ahah

Comment: The term you're looking for is "*Hadamard matrix*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks a lot for this comment about Hadamard Matrices. This guidance was exactly what I was looking for. I will read more about this. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to see that there is a $(2^r) \times (2^r)$ solution matrix for each integer $r\geq 2$. Indeed, consider a matrix $A=(a_{I,J})$ where the two indices $I$ and $J$ are subsets of $\lbrace 1,2,\ldots ,r \rbrace$, and

$$a(I,J)=(-1)^{|I\cap J|}$$

Let us show that this matrix is indeed orthogonal. Let $I_1 \neq I_2$, we must show that the sum

$$
S(I_1,I_2)=\sum_{J\subseteq [r]} a(I_1,J)a(I_2,J) \tag{2}
$$

is zero. If $A\cup B$ is any partition of $[r]$, we can decompose $S(I_1,I_2)$ using this partition, and rewrite it as

$$
S(I_1,I_2)=\sum_{J_A\subseteq A}\sum_{J_B\subseteq B} a(I_1,J_A)a(I_1,J_B)a(I_2,J_A)a(I_2,J_B) \tag{2'}
$$

In particular, if we take $A=I_1\cup I_2$ and $B=[r] \setminus A$ in (2'), the terms $a(I_1,J_B)$ and $a(I_2,J_B)$ are always equal to 1, so

$$
S(I_1,I_2)=2^{|B|} \sum_{J_A\subseteq A} \sum_{J_B\subseteq B} a(I_1,J_A)a(I_2,J_B) \tag{3}
$$

In other words, we may assume without loss that $I_1\cup I_2 = [r]$. Similarly, using (2') again with  $A=I_1\cap I_2$, we may also assume without loss that $I_1\cap I_2 = \emptyset$.

At this point $(I_1,I_2)$ is a partition of $[r]$. We may then use (2') a third time, with $A=I_1,B=I_2$ :

$$
S(I_1,I_2)=\sum_{J_A\subseteq I_1}\sum_{J_B\subseteq I_2} a(I_1,J_A)a(I_1,J_B)a(I_2,J_A)a(I_2,J_B)=
\sum_{J_A\subseteq I_1}\sum_{J_B\subseteq I_2}(-1)^{|J_A|+|J_B|}=
\bigg(\sum_{J_A\subseteq I_1}(-1)^{|J_A|}\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{J_B\subseteq I_2}(-1)^{|J_B|}\bigg)
 \tag{4}
$$

Now each factor in this product is zero, using the Newton binomial for $(1-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PeterTaylor for guiding me in the right direction.
This problem comes under the genre of construction of Hadamard matrices which are orthogonal matrices built using only 1 and -1 as elements.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix

There are many constructions possible for big matrices of size $2^k $ like Sylvestors construction:
Sylvester's construction(From Wikipedia) :

Examples of Hadamard matrices were actually first constructed by James Joseph Sylvester in 1867. Let H be a Hadamard matrix of order n. Then the partitioned matrix

\begin{bmatrix}H&H\\H&-H\end{bmatrix} 
is a Hadamard matrix of order 2n. This observation can be applied repeatedly and leads to the following sequence of matrices, also called Walsh matrices.

\begin{aligned}H_{1}&={\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}},\\H_{2}&={\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}},\\H_{4}&={\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}},\end{aligned}

Also construction of such matrices of arbitrary sizes is still under research with an open conjecture called the Hadamard conjecture which states that a Hadamard matrix of order 4k exists for every positive integer k.

Just a fun fact to add: These matrices are extremely useful especially for error correcting codes to correct messages transmitted over very unreliable channels.